# python can't find conda packages but can find pip packages

Tags: python, pip, conda

I'm sure this might be a common problem but I've scoured the StackOverflow and read through all the recommended posts that StackOverflow gave me before posting. However, I've installed tensorflow on conda but not on pip. When I run Python, I can't run `import tensorflow` since it gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'`. This leads me to believe that conda installs the packages to a different place than pip, but I'm not sure how to make them install to the same place. I recall a long time ago, the problem being related to usr/bin and usr/local/bin or something, but I don't remember how that goes or the solution.

Any links / tips would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm assuming that the current active conda environment is where you've installed tensorflow. Is tensorflow displayed when you type in `conda list`?

Comment: How are you running your Python? Is Anaconda absolutely necessary, or can you just `pip install tensorflow` and be done with it?

Comment: Hi y'all, thanks for the answers! Tensorflow is displayed with conda list. Anaconda isn't necessary for now, but I was just wondering why this would be a problem in this case. I know that I can use virtual environments and whatnot to help with package management, but I would just like to know what's going on in this case for future debugging.Thanks so much!

Comment: Your `pip` and `conda` calls might point to different `python` installations. Check where your `python` and `pip` calls are pointing to

Comment: How do I check these calls?

Comment: Hi @FlyingTeller, I still haven't been able to figure this out. What's the best way to check where these calls are pointing? Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your OS, type `which python` or `where python` in the terminal and do the same with `pip`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

The below command will list all the environments in the system and their path

```
conda env list
```

Please activate the corresponding environment using the below command

```
conda activate <env_name>
```

You can list the pip/conda packages that you have installed in the activated environment using the below command

```
pip freeze
conda list
```

If tensorflow is not listing, please install tensorflow again using the below command

pip install tensorflow

If still you are facing issue check the PATH variable in control panel and set python path.

Comment: I could just use pip install tensorflow, but how would I fix the path thing / set Python path? I think that's what I'm confused about.

Comment: Control Panel\System and Security\System ===> Edit the system environment variables ==> Advanced ==>Environment variables. There set Path="path where your python.exe file is present"

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Mac?